# R - filter out rows containing a string more than once in column X

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

If I have an R dataframe, how can I filter out rows that contain a string, "Item", more than once in a column of interest?

| row_number | column | column_of_interest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blahblahblah | Item 1A |
| 2 | Blah | Item blahblah Item |
| 3 | Blahblahblahblah | Item 1A Item 2 Item 3 |

I would only want to keep row 1.

Comment: Which column items have to be matched?  I cannot understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is called `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(str_count(column_of_interest, "Item") == 1)
```

---

Update based on comment from TO:

If the conditional check should be non case-sensitive, the following would work:

```
df %>%
  filter(str_count(tolower(column_of_interest), "item") == 1)
```

Comment: thank you. how do I make it not-case sensitive?